# Adding keys to superglobals in php

Tags: php, session

Is there any way by which I can add keys to superglobals in php without defining the corresponding values to those key?

For example:

`$_SESSION['key']='set';//`key` automatically gets defined.

But I want to do something like this

`add_key($_SESSION,'key')`//key is added to `$_SESSION` array.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, you just have to pass the first argument by reference. I'm not sure why you want it though:

```
add_key(array &$var, $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $var))
        $var[$key] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just set it to an empty string? or `empty`? or `NULL`?

What is it you want to happen when you access `$_SESSION['key']` after calling `add_key($_SESSION, 'key')`?